# Facing issue with Knockout binding like "Unable to parse bindings."

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am new to Knockout Js.
I am trying to bind values,some times the value is getting  binded and some times it s giving me :
Unable to parse bindings.
Bindings value: text: parentName
Message: parentName is not defined;

How do i make sure it gets binded everytime?
here is my code:

```
var vm= = function() {
            Id: ko.observable();
            Name: ko.observable();
            description: ko.observable();
            parentName:ko.observable();
}
var getUserGroup = function(Id) {
            var ajaxOptions = {
                url: 'Api/Group/Get?id=' + Id,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json'
            };

            function gotUserGroup(data) {

                vm.Id = data.Id;
                vm.Name = data.name;
                vm.description = data.description;
                vm.parentName =getName(data.parentId)  
return data;              
            }

    function getName(data.Id)
    {
                var ajaxOptions = {
                   url: 'Api/Client/Get?Id=' + Id,
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json'
                };
                function getValue(data) {
                    return data.name;

                }

               $.ajax(ajaxOptions).then(getValue);
    }

            return $.ajax(ajaxOptions).then(gotUserGroup).then(getName);
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var vm = {
            Id: ko.observable(),
            Name: ko.observable(),
            description: ko.observable(),
            parentName:ko.observable()
}
```

(I replaced ";" with ",")

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I have tried your suggestion.It did not work.

Comment: Can you make jsfiddle? I'll try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

```
    var vm = {
                Id: ko.observable(),
                Name: ko.observable(),
                description: ko.observable(),
                parentName:ko.observable()
    }
    var getUserGroup = function(Id) {
                var ajaxOptions = {
                    url: 'Api/Group/Get?id=' + Id,
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json'
                };

                function gotUserGroup(data) {

                    vm.Id (data.Id);
                    vm.Name (data.name);
                    vm.description (data.description);

    return data;              
                }
  function getName(data.Id)
    {
                var ajaxOptions = {
                   url: 'Api/Client/Get?Id=' + Id,
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json'
                };
                function getValue(data) {
                     vm.parentName (data.name); 

                }

               $.ajax(ajaxOptions).then(getValue);
    }

            return $.ajax(ajaxOptions).then(gotUserGroup).then(getName);
        };
```